# Count unique users from statistics table based on hourly groupby

Tags: mysql

We have a statistical database for our Facebook application. One of our outputs is Unique Facebook Users based on time range. If our customers select daily usage, we show them a graph of unique Facebook users per hour.

My problem is with the unique values. First, here is the relevant columns from the table:

```
timestamp---facebookID---actionID---producerID
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp) as Hour, COUNT(DISTINCT facebookID) as Events 
FROM `e4s_analytic_data` 
WHERE actionID = 'ax' AND producerID = '2' AND timestamp BETWEEN'12-06-11 0:00:00' and '12-06-11 23:59:59'
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

This gives unique visitors (Based on `facebookID`) per hour. But if `id = 123` visited in 14 and then visited again in 17, He will be counted twice - firstly in 14 and then in 17.

To solve this I've tried to add an inner query that will give all the ids that are already in the table from earlier hours.

I thought to bring all facebookIDs already listed in the table from 0 (The start of the day) until the current hour (taken from each row from the outside `SELECT`) and remove them from the outside `SELECT`. So that every `COUNT` will only include new Facebook IDs. Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp) as Hour, COUNT(DISTINCT facebookID) as Events 
FROM `e4s_analytic_data` 
WHERE actionID = 'ax' AND producerID = '2' AND timestamp between '12-06-11 0:00:00' and '12-06-11 23:59:59' 
AND facebookID NOT IN
    ( SELECT facebookID FROM `e4s_analytic_data`
      WHERE actionID = 'ax' AND producerID = '2' AND    
      HOUR(timestamp) >= 0 AND HOUR(timestamp) < Hour
    )
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Unknown column 'Hour' in 'where clause'
```

How can I solve this ?
Thanks.

**EDIT: Sample data:**

```
timestamp--------------facebookID--------producerID-------actionID
2012-06-13 12:38:55  ******6513406        2               ax
2012-06-13 08:49:55  ******6513406        2               ax
```

The query returns 1 unique visitor at 8 and 1 unique visitor at 12. I want to return only 1 unique at 8, because at 12 it is the same visitor from 8.

Comment: The problem is trying to access something from the outer query in the inner one. I think this might do what you want it to: SELECT MAX(HOUR(timestamp)) as h, COUNT(DISTINCT facebookID) as Events FROM `e4s_analytic_data` WHERE actionID = 'ax' AND producerID = '2' AND timestamp between '12-06-11 0:00:00' and '12-06-11 23:59:59' GROUP BY h P.S. Why not choose something that's not a keyword for your column alias?

Comment: I get the same error, `Unknown column 'h' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Yeah I see the problem now - this should have been a comment really. It's probably possible to achieve this without the sub-query; I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, is it not just a matter of selecting MAX(HOUR(timestamp)) rather than the sub-query? Edited.

Comment: No, In each hour the graph shows how many unique Facebook ids have used the application. So you need each HOUR(timestamp) and not only the MAX.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with some sample data and expected output? I'm not awake enough to understand I'm afraid!!

Comment: Added sample data, current output and expected output.